# Jquery UI Tabs - tab active only with content

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

any help gratefully received

I am trying to get a tab to be active ("clickable") only if there is content present within the div. The content will come from a php sql query.

In it's simplest form

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Hello</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Goodbye</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
if Query returned result, echo results, tabs-1 active
</div>

<div id="tabs-2">
if Query returned 0 results, nothing to echo tabs-2 inactive
</div>
</div>
```

I guess the active/inactive part does not have to be based on the query result - number of characters in the div or size of div may both be indicators I could use to see if the div is empty.

I know very little about javascript so if there is a solution out there is it possible you could explain it as you were speaking to a small child...

Many thanks in advance and I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the tab change event using `select`, something like:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.panel).html().length < 1) {
            alert('no content!');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input although I didn't really get it to work in the fashion I needed.  I manged to cobble together something based on the number of records returned from the query 

if (artist_no_gigs==0)  {
 $(function () {
   $("#artist_tabs").tabs({disabled:[ 1]});
   });
} although this does not work if I wish to disable multiple tab